# Explain ADFS claim rules

Tags: saml, saml-2.0, adfs

I have many clients that uses SSO, for that we use SAML 2. Many of my clients uses providers like Okta, PingIdentity and a bunch of them ADFS. Doing the integration with ADFS always at the beginning raises and error, and then they fix this with the following setup on their side:

**Transform Incoming Claim**

- Incoming claim = UPN
- Outgoing Claim = Name ID
- Outgoing name ID format = Email

The error that we saw on the saml reponse is that they do not send a nameID, instead we see this:

```
<samlp:Status><samlp:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Requester"><samlp:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:InvalidNameIDPolicy"/></samlp:StatusCode></samlp:Status>
```

This is just happening with ADFS integrations, and I want to know what should I know about claim rules on ADFS in order to underestand this error and explain to my following clients that uses ADFS.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Transform claim rule.

In the client metadata, you should see something like:

```
<md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress</md:NameIDFormat>
        <md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient</md:NameIDFormat>
        <md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent</md:NameIDFormat>
```

These are the allowed NameID formats.

The outgoing NameID format needs to be one of these.

So e.g. email would be:

```
Incoming claim = Email

Outgoing Claim = NameID

Outgoing name ID format = Email
```

You would first have the normal email LDAP rule and then the Transform rule as above.